# Filter some objects from the array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects. I am trying to filter some objects from the array and get a new array using the following.

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "title": "title 1",
    "body": "Body for user 1",
    "address": {
      "country": "Germany",
      "state": "State1"
    },
    "phone": 1234
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "title": "title 2",
    "body": "Body for user 2",
    "address": {
      "country": "Canada",
      "state": "State2"
    },
    "phone": 4321
  }
]
```

How can i filter the array and get the new array without `address` and `phone`.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You literally dont show any attempts at anything.

Comment: You should post what you've tried so far. If you haven't tried anything yet, you should check out Array.prototype.map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map and report back.

Comment: @Derek `filter` will only include elements that pass the bool condition provided in filter. This problem is modifying the objects contained in the array, not filtering out elements of the array. Although I do agree with your sentiment of "please try and come up with something first" on such a low-effort post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.map()` and Object destructuring:

```js
let data = [
    {"userId": 1, "title": "title 1", "body": "Body for user 1", "address": {"country": "Germany", "state": "State1"}, "phone": 1234},
    {"userId": 2, "title": "title 2", "body": "Body for user 2", "address": { "country": "Canada", "state": "State2"}, "phone": 4321}
];

let result = data.map(({address, phone, ...rest}) => rest);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Object Destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

Comment: Thanks.. This is looks nice to me and works perfect.

Comment: @Derek how are you going to change the returned objects with filter? The callback to filter returns a boolean.

Comment: Nice use of `...rest`. That's very pretty.

Comment: Very nice indeed!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to create a new filtered array.

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array

You can use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get and return the properties you wish to keep:

```
data.map(({userId, title, body}) => {
  return {userId, title, body}
});
```

Here's a demo:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "title": "title 1",
    "body": "Body for user 1",
    "address": {
      "country": "Germany",
      "state": "State1"
    },
    "phone": 1234
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "title": "title 2",
    "body": "Body for user 2",
    "address": {
      "country": "Canada",
      "state": "State2"
    },
    "phone": 4321
  }
];

let res = [];
res = data.map(({userId, title, body}) => {
  return {userId, title, body}
});

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Or, you know, they could use the `filter()` helper

Comment: @Derek using `filter` you get the same object structure, and OP wants to get different objects, not filter by a condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use reduce

```
let res = Object.values(data.reduce((c, {userId,title,body}) => {
      c[userId] = c[userId] || {userId, title, body}
      return c;
 }, {}));
```